# Access Instagram user data without logging in

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, screen-scraping

I want to get data returned by this API:

https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username=kateannedesigns

When we search for a user we can access basic data without even logging in but when I make a request using this api which actually fetches the data, it fails with a 400 response.

This is the request shown in the browser:

[image]

[image]

[image]

There is no session ID but it still works in the browser
**but I want to use this in python requests.**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Instagram banned my IP because I sent too many requests. I could find out that the API expects the `X-IG-App-ID` header with a number. I am not sure whether or not it actually needs the 15 digit number. Try this code:

```
import requests

headers = {'X-IG-App-ID': '743845927482847'} # random 15 digit number
response = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username=kateannedesigns', headers=headers)

json_data = response.json() 

print(response.status_code)
print(json_data)
```